# Restricting public access for GCE Ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I have a requirement where-in we have to restrict the ip address of the GCE Ingress

Applied the annotation :

```
 kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: x.x.x.x
```

Also i have added a spec the service which is using this ingress as below:

externalTrafficPolicy: Local

Still the firewall restrictions are not applied. i am able to access the [www.abcd.com](http://www.abcd.com) site out side of x.x.x.x ip range.

Comment: Can you update your question with little more details ? Provide a little more information about your setup and what have you tried already and what exactly you want to achieve (restrit which resources to whom, and the opposite).

Comment: @Wojtek_B., We are running a Microservice Kind of Architecture and we have a storefront which is having a service and a ingress., the site can be either accessible through the URL defined in the ingress or the ingress external ip . Now i want to restrict the access when connected to VPN to both this IP and the URL defined in the ingress.  Let me know if any further details required.

Comment: Please describe your network topology a little better - what is where and how the restriction has to work exactly.

Comment: @Wojtek_B.,  We have an External Ingress, We have a fontend application service., The request coming from the Ingress is route frontend application service which is of type Node port. Now i have to restrict the IP address of the External Ingress so that its not available for the public . Only when we connect to a VPN it should be able to access

Comment: So - you basically want to disable access from the Internet and allow access to your application only from "inside" for VPN users ? Have you tried creating additional rule in [GCP's Firewall](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) ?